Timedatectl output does not change after running ntpdate command in Kali Linux
I am currently doing a pen testing CTF challenge on HacktheBox.com (HTB) that involves manipulation of Kerberos TGT tickets so need to sync my local system time on my Kali Linux instance with the system time on the remote HTB machine.
With a VPN connection to the remote HTB  machine while logged in as root user, I ran the following command which worked fine.
ntpdate -u [IP of host HTB machine]
Yet, the output of timedatectl command does not show the local system time as having been updated. The ntp sync feature was disabled already via timedatectl command before running ntpdate
When I request a TGT ticket from remote HTB machine, I get the error that clock skew is too great.
How do I get my local time and remote HTB server time to match so I can get TGT ticket?

The fact that timedatectl indicates the time was unchanged suggests that ntpdate may not actually have worked. Please run ntpdateagain with the -d option and see if you actually get a usable NTP response or not.
